# First Craft website: how to organize different content

Tags: entries, sections

I am new to Craft and read a lot of arctilces and most of the docs. Most parts are quite easy. Now I plan how to organize all the different parts and pages.

Below is a simple outline. Not every page, but to get the ieda.

```
Home                            (Single)
- News                          (Section; structure: news)
  - Posts                       (news entry with category post?)
  - Press                       (news entry with category press?)
  - Media                       …
  - Events                      …
- About                         (Section; structure: pages)
  - About us                    (pages entry with defult entry type)
  - History                     (pages entry with defult entry type)
  - Team                        (pages entry with defult entry type)
- People                        
  - Locations                   (Section; channel: location)
  - Page-A, Page-B, etc…        (? other entry types)
- Members                       (Section; structure: pages)
  - Info                        (pages entry with defult entry type)
  - Jobs                        (?)
  - Listing                     (pages entry with defult entry type)
  - Register/Login              (?)
  - (PROTECTED MEMBERS AREA)    (?)
    - Auth-Group-I
      - Page A, Page B, …
    - Auth-Group-II
      - Page-A, Page-B, …
```

**First:**
There are 4 different "sections" (in terms of the content and audience). Would it be possible/a good idea to put alle those into one Craft section, titled pages?
And on those pages, where I need other content, like locations (store locator), I pull data from a dedicated section titled locations. Or on another I query the job listings.
That way I can group most pages, create the hierachy and spearate the content in logical groups/sections.

**Second:**
Otherwise, would it be better to give each website section its own Craft section.

**Third:**
What about those "special pages" like my register/login form, the job lsiting page, etc. Do they become a Single?

**Fourth:**
What is more appropriate for my different news pages: using categories or entry types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try answer each question as best as I can... Feel free to ask for more information if you still have questions.

---

**First:** For your use case, it might indeed by a good idea to put all actual pages in 1 structure, it allows you to better visualise the content structure. You can than pull in the required news, locations, jobs content with corresponding fields.

---

**Second:** It depends on how many pages you'll have, if you put it all in one big structure, and you have to many pages in there, you might loose the overview. From what you lined out, I'd put it in 1 structure, and you can still use different entry types if you need different content.

---

**Third:** Singles are ment to be one-off pages, mostly with a specific design, but yes, pages for registering, logging in are excellent candidates for singles. Once you'll use the fields or design on it more often, you might be better off putting it as an extra type in a section.

Specifically for Jobs, if those are again their own set of entries (I'd put them in a channel) you can use `jobs/index.html` as template for your overview page (assuming you specified `jobs/_entry` as path when registering the section).

---

**Fourth:** It all depends on how much the content itself will vary between posts, press and media. IF you'll need a different set of fields, you'll be better off creating different entry types. If however they'll all follow the same set of fields, you can work with categories to differentiate between the different pages.

Comment: Many thanks! When I put all content pages (~50) in one section, I have to use, many, entry types (called jobs, locations, events, etc.) to get the special pages to pull data from the corresponding sections (jobs, locations, events, etc.). That is the "right use"? Or is there a more "craft way" of doing that?

Comment: You can try and limit the amount of different entry types you need by using a matrix field with repeatable blocks you can add in different combinations. You can even use those to pull in content from  other sections such as jobs, locations, ...

Comment: Ok, thanks. There are a lot of conceptual similarities to WP like 'custom post types', how categories and tags work, etc. That makes it easier to understand :-)

Comment: True, but linking them all together is really easy, as you can directly link one entry to another by using the `entry` type field.